# VS code Remote Container : Shell server terminated (code: 126, signal: null) unable to find user xxx: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run python code from docker using Visual Studio Code extension Remote Container. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV BLOB_CONTAINER_SAS_CONNECTION="secret"
ENV ROUND_LEVEL="0"
# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt



WORKDIR /app
COPY [ ".env", "/app"]
ADD /src/sample_code_round_data_docker.py /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
ARG USERNAME=someuser
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    #
    # [Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting.
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME


# [Optional] Set the default user. Omit if you want to keep the default as root.
USER $USERNAME
# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "sample_code_round_data_docker.py"]
```

And here is .devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",

    "context": "..",

    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",

    "settings": { 
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": null
    },
    "extensions": [],
     "remoteUser": "someuser"
}
```

When i run it, it throws an error:

```
Shell server terminated (code: 126, signal: null)
unable to find user someuser: no matching entries in passwd file
```

When I search for the `passwd` file inside container:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

There is no user `someuser`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. For me I had forgotten to create my vscode user at first, so I modified my image to create the vscode user, but vscode did not update to use the new image.

I had to manually remove the (old) container vscode was trying to use. If you go to

> Remote Containers: Show Logs

You can see the ID of the container VSCode is trying to use.

You can then kill and remove the container with:

```
docker kill $YOUR_ID_HERE
docker rm $YOUR_ID_HERE
```

Then tell vscode to try opening the project in a remote container again. It will be forced to create a new container using the updated image.

Comment: How do you create a user?

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue but there were actually 2 parts of this problem for me.

**The first half** was that I was basing some of my configurations from the vscode sample remote containers including the following line in my devcontainer.json:

```
// Comment out this line to run as root instead.
"remoteUser": "vscode"
```

But I was also trying to use one of my own docker images, so the user `vscode` didn't exist in my docker image. If you just comment the configuration line out or just switch it to a user you know exists (i.e maybe `root`), then that will solve things assuming you are starting from a clean or new container.

**The second half** was, like `Increasingly Idiotic` had stated, that you may need to close/remove the old container as it maybe saving your prior username, even if you already have updated your devcontainer.json file. Thus rebuilding will fail even with an updated `remoteUser` value.